# why does in_array(0,*) always return 1

Tags: php

why would `in_array(0, array("pop"))` return 1?

see [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) clearly 0 is not a value in the array and this should return 0 or FALSE.

Comment: If the third parameter strict is set to TRUE then the in_array() function will also check the types of the needle in the haystack. - http://php.net/en/in_array

Comment: In a manual that you already provided theres a string `Searches haystack for needle using loose comparison unless strict is set.` You know what is __loose comparison__, don't you?

Comment: It's a feature, not a bug....   My guess is that `(int)'pop' = 0`

Comment: The loose type check is done by casting everything to int. You can check that `intval` of a string that doesn't have numbers is always 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`in_array($needle, $haystack, $strict = FALSE)`](http://php.net/en/in_array) searches haystack for needle using **loose comparison** unless strict is set.
When you don't provide third "strict" argument the values will be compared according to loose comparsion rules in php. 
Go to http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php. You'll see this loose comparison behavior documented.

`0 == "pop"` is a loose comparison returning TRUE

`0 === "pop"` is a strict comparison returning FALSE